# Tilt an image on titling to any angle

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to tilt an image at any angle but I am not able to do so
Here I am providing the code i have worked on.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        text1.setText("X: " + x);
        text2.setText("Y: " + y);
        text3.setText("Z: " + z);
        if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) {
            if (x < 0) {
                //Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                //iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); // required
                //matrix.postRotate((float) 25, x, y);
                //iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
             iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
            }
            if (x > 0) {

                 iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
            }
        } else {
            if (y < 0) {

                 iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
            }
            if (y > 0) {

                 iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
            }
        }
        if (x > (-2) && x < (2) && y > (-2) && y < (2)) {

             iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
        }   }}
```

.Could anyone suggest how to acheive that

Comment: so the sensor is working but the imageview is not rotating ?

Answer (score 3):

you should try something as the following to rotate your imageView :

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: but from where will I get angle

Answer (score 2):

Its quite Simple.You don't need to write this much code.Use yourImageView.setRotation(Rotation_angle) to tilt the image  by certain degrees as per the value of Rotation_angle.

You can ask if you have any further queries.Happy coding :)

Comment: Rotaion_angle?? from where

Comment: I mean set any random float value..like img.setRotation(90.0f);

Comment: its not working i tried float angley = (float) (y * (Math.PI / 180));

Comment: @ jigar Pandya iv.setRotation(anglex);

Comment: first set anglex to any static value...like 45.0f or 90.0f

Comment: you dont need anglex and angley..just one value is enough

Comment: @ Jigar Pandya I want it to tilt by automatically detecting angle something like in temple run

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46231/discussion-between-poojagupta-and-jigar-pandya)

Comment: try tp print your angle first in logcat and check wether is it printing correct value ??

Comment: 01-28 12:49:24.591: I/System.out(5114): angley0.17062724
01-28 12:49:34.471: I/System.out(5114): anglex0.0

Comment: see your anglex and angley values are approximately zero so it will gove negligible effect to image..try some bigger values and see wether is it rotating..?

Comment: @poojagupta :accept the answer so that others can use it if it has helped you any way!!

Comment: share your piece of code where you are trying to rotate Image!!if you say,I'l give you my code!!

Comment: @ Jigar Pandya I have posted it as an answer Please check it once